# Is there a Twitter client for Mac that doesn't need a user+password login (uses OAuth)?

Tags: macos, authentication, twitter

Are there any Twitter client for Mac that don't need a user+password login (but uses OAuth instead)?

Answer (score 1):

Adium 1.4, just updated over the weekend, is an open-source multi-protocol native OS X chat client that now supports Twitter using OAuth. I've never been a fan of AIR apps, and use Adium already, so this was a natural. Your timeline can be updated at an interval you select .

Comment: I am using it for IM, and when did set up Twitter OAuth on Adium, my contact list was invaded with all my twitter contacts ( the ones I am Following ). Is there any way to organize/separate Twitter contacts from other IM contacts ?

Comment: They should show up in a separate "Twitter" list that you can collapse, just like Offline or Buddies. You may need to look at your Adium Settings for whether Groups are shown. But there is a check-box in the Options pane of the Twitter account prefs to turn off display of Twitter contacts.